# Java euro symbol is converted to currency symbol

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a double variable to a price string (example: €59,00) using NumberFormat

Here is the method I written:

```
private String formatValue (double price){
  NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ITALIAN);
  String value = f.format(new BigDecimal(price));
  return value;
}
```

then, I write the returned value in a pdf field using iText library.

```
form.setField("value", formatValue(price));
```

Now, when I open the generated pdf in a browser's pdf viewer (like chrome or firefox), the field looks like:
€59,00

but when I open it in adobe reader, or I try to physically print, it appears like
¤59,00.

If I open the variable *value* in debug, I see the string formatted as ¤59,00.

What I'm doing wrong?

---

I solved using DecimalFormat instead NumberFormat, and passing the € symbol in utf-8 encode (an input by mwhs [thanks])

```
private String formatValue (double price){
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20ac0.00");   
  String value = formatter.format(price);
  return value;    
}
```

Comment: Did you read this article on Unicode and Character Sets? It will help you better understand your problem! [http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I think all the answers here including your own solution fail to address the original puzzle: Why is the PDF rendered differenty in the browser and in Reader, when PDF is supposed to look exactly the same under all circumstances? OTOH, that would not be a Java question.

Answer (score 2):

You may be using separate encoding. Browsers may be using UTF-8, Whereas adobe reader may be using ANSI or another localization of UTF. (Note these are not necessarily the encoding they use, just an example) so check your preferences, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the actual UTF-8 Euro symbol which makes the code more readable.

```
  private static final DecimalFormat EURO_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("€0.00");
  private String formatValue (double price){
    return EURO_FORMAT.format(price);
  }
```

But the java.util.NumberFormat is a better choice since you can use the Locale for the correct number format. In France, Germany and the Netherlands the comma is used instead of the decimal point before the cents. But the format for thousands is different. See below for an example:

```
public class NumberFormatLocaleExample {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    double price = 1249.69;
    System.out.println(formatValueGermany(price));
    System.out.println(formatValueFrance(price));
  }

  private static final NumberFormat EURO_FORMAT_GER = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
  private static String formatValueGermany(double price){
    return String.format("€%s", EURO_FORMAT_GER.format(price));
  }

  private static final NumberFormat EURO_FORMAT_FRANCE = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRENCH);

  private static String formatValueFrance(double price){
    return String.format("€%s", EURO_FORMAT_FRANCE.format(price));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the Locale: you are using ITALIAN, correct would be ITALY, because ITALIAN may refer to other countries where they speak Italian, but ITALY means the country with its units including the currency.

```
private String formatValue (double price){
  NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ITALY);
  String value = f.format(new BigDecimal(price));
  return value;
}
```

Would give you the right Euro-symbol. Same is true for GERMAN vs. GERMANY or FRENCH vs. FRANCE btw.

Comment: It _is_ a good idea to use `Locale.ITALY`, but why did the OP get the Euro sign in the browser-rendered PDF, but not in Acrobat Reader?